# How to create a table and insert data with dynamic values in postgres

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I am trying to write a stored procedure where the table name comes dynamically. 
Also it has to check whether the table already exists and create only if it does not exist.

Then later I am trying to insert data into the table like below.
Here I am passing `pkey` and `filedata` as parameters to insert query in which `pkey` is a string and `filedata` is a json data which looks like `{ "customer": "John Doe", "items": {"product": "Beer","qty": 6}}`

I have tried the below query but the table is not getting created it is giving the message

Notice: identifier public.tablename_11111 will be truncated to public.tablename_11111

here the table name is `public.tablename_11111`

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.generate_table(tb_name text)
    RETURNS text LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100 VOLATILE AS $BODY$

    BEGIN
        EXECUTE format('
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %I(
               id serial PRIMARY KEY,
               pkey VARCHAR (250)  NULL,
               fpo_data TEXT NULL
            )', tb_name || '_pk');


            EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO' || tb_name || '_pk (pkey, fpo_data) VALUES
        ('|| pkey ||', '|| filedata ||')';

        END;
    $BODY$;
```

Answer (score 0):

First: `%I`, when used with a name like `public.tablename_11111`, won't do what you want.

You will end up with a table called `"public.tablename_11111"`, not with a table `tablename_11111` in schema `public`. For that, you should separate schema and table name and use the format `%I.%I`:

```
EXECUTE
   format(
      'CREATE TABLE %I.%I (...)',
      schema_name, tb_name || '_pk'
   );
```

Second, your `INSERT` statement is vulnerable to SQL injection. You must use the `format` function there as well, just like in `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: I tried replacing %I with %I.%I am getting the below error ERROR:  too few arguments for format()

Comment: Right, I said you should separate schema and table name. I should have said: make schema and table two different function paramers, and feed both to `format`. Each `%` pattern in the format string must have a corresponding argument.

Comment: Can you please type it. I am not getting exactly what you are trying to say

Comment: Thak you. I tried your code the Stored procedure is running fine now, but when I try to run select * from public.tablename_11111, I am getting the error like relation " public.tablename_11111" does not exist

Comment: No, that cannot be. What you are *really* running must be `select * from "public.tablename_11111";`. Note the double quotes that make PostgreSQL treat it as a single identifier rather than a schema qualified table. Perhaps you are using some tool that misguidedly adds those quotes for you.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should pass the schema name and table name as two separate values. And it's better to not concatenate values into a SQL string, but use placeholders. Mainly so that you don't need to worry about formatting them correctly.

Something like the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.generate_table(tb_schema text, tb_name text, ???)
RETURNS text 
  LANGUAGE plpgsql --<< the language name is an identifier, don't quote it
  COST 100 VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
  tb_name := tb_name ||'_pk';

  EXECUTE format('
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %I.%I (
           id serial PRIMARY KEY,
           pkey VARCHAR (250)  NULL,
           fpo_data TEXT NULL
        )', tb_schema, tb_name);

  -- where do pkey and filedata come from? 
  EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO %I.%I (pkey, fpo_data) VALUES (:1, :2)', 
                 tb_schema, tb_name)
      using pkey, filedata;  

END;
$BODY$;
```